# Link Console Application with MFC Application in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, googletest

I have a MFC project. I want to write unit tests for it using googletest. For that, I made a Win32 console application that contains all the unit tests. I put both these projects in a single solution.

The problem is that when I build that solution I got the following linking error:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CTest_MFC_AppApp::CTest_MFC_AppApp(void)" (??0CTest_MFC_AppApp@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall SimpleTests_TestAsserts_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@SimpleTests_TestAsserts_Test@@EAEXXZ)   main.obj

I've tried everything I could think of, including recreating the unit test project with and without precompiled headers. Can anyone shed some light on this problem? Thank you!